# Is a Form accessible in .NET before it has a handle?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have run across a strange piece of code inside a `Control`.

```
if (ParentForm != null)
{
  traceBlock.Log("ParentForm is null");

  if (!ParentForm.IsHandleCreated)
  {
    ParentForm.HandleCreated += (sender, e) =>
        {
          var text = PhysDocContext.Document.GetHeader(PhysDocContext);
          ParentForm.Text = text;
        };
  }
}
```

This code fires a few times with `ParentForm == null`.  It's obvious the logger is logging inaccurate information.   What really strikes me as odd is checking for `IsHandleCreated`.  In my mind this code will never fire.  So the event won't hook and the header will never be set.

What's even more odd is that the ParentForm is set to a `Panel` control owned by the parent form.  It is also set by the Form that is the parent.  Leading me to believe this is a more impossible situation.

Is it normal (possible even) for a `Form` to be accessible in .NET that has no handle?

Comment: It eventually will have a handle.  This block of code seems incomplete.  It seems this block of code is because of a requirement that surrounds `PhysDocContext`

Comment: The code requires that the Form has been created and the form doesn't have a handle.  From what I gathered so far, this code can run but will have to be called early in the lifecycle of the Form.  Another major concern I have with this setup.

Comment: Ask yourself a simpler question. If it were *not* possible, for what reason do the `IsHandleCreated` method and the `HandleCreated` event exist?

Comment: `PhysDocContext` is solely being used to pass down the connection string from this higher layer code to the DL (entity framework).  A bad design IMO.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - It's possible that the property was inherited from a base class, but has no meaning in the child class `Form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it normal (possible even) for a Form to be accessible in .NET that has no handle?

Yes, because a Form (or a Control for that matter) is merely a wrapper class around a few Win32 API calls. The code you use to create a form is used to create the .NET object.

Most likely only when the form is shown, the calls to Win32 are made, finally giving the control a handle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. The handle is the window handle of the form and it may not be created until the form actually has a window (visible or invisible).